# Why does 2147483647 is the only Int that the code I wrote does'nt get the right feedback?

Tags: java, integer, primes

I wrote a code that finds if a number is prime or not.
for every prime number it prints the number + is prime
for every number that isn't prime it prints the number=the lowest divider*the highest divider

only for the biggest int (2147483647) it prints the second line all though it is a prime number...
why so?

the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindDivisors2meth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = myScanner.nextInt();
        boolean isPrime = true;
        int p = 2;
        while( p * p <= n & isPrime ) {
            if( n % p == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
            else {
                p = p + 1;
            }
        }
        if( isPrime) {
            System.out.println(n + " is prime");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(n + "=" + p + "*" + n/p);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Now is your chance to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) --- For me, when the input is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`= 2147483647`), the program prints out `2147483647=2147483647*1`

Comment: Tangential: consider where you can stop checking for larger numbers, and a more efficient way of doing that check 

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Answer (score 2):

2147483647 is the largest number that possibly fits in an `int`. You see, `int` does not mean 'any integral number'. It actually means: an integral number that fits in 32-bits - treating it as a signed (represented with 2's complement) number.

The upshot is, 2^31-1 is the largest positive number that 'fits', and -2^31 is the largest negative number that 'fits'. These numbers wrap around:

```
int x = 2147483647;
System.out.println(x == Integer.MAX_VALUE); // true
x++;
System.out.println(x); // -2147483648
System.out.println(x == Integer.MIN_VALUE); // true
x--;
System.out.println(x); // 2147483647
```

Crucially, then, `p * p <= n` **can not ever be false**, because n is the largest possible int, and therefore, **no number** can be larger than it. Hence your `while` loop runs forever, and, eventually, after a very large amount of loops, the value of `p` hits 2147483647. At which point you loop one more time, and now p is -2147483648. You keep looping a lot more and eventually (after 4294967293 times, in fact!), `p` ends up being 1, and now finally `n % p`  is indeed `0`, so, `isPrime` is set to false and that's how your loop ends - the only way it can, by `isPrime` being false, given that `p * p <= n` can't be false (`X <= n` for any X where `n` is the maximum int value can never be false, think about it. How can a number not be 'less than or equal' to the largest number in existence)?

### Solutions

1. Use `long` instead. This buys you a bit of space; longs are 64-bit but otherwise identical, and therefore go up to 2^63-1 and down to -2^63, i.e. about 18 digits worth. You'll still have an issue if someone enters exactly 2^63-1, unless.. you continue to use `.nextInt()`, but **assign** it to a `long`. Now you don't have that problem!
2. Special-case it. The real problem here is that `p*p` becomes negative (because any result above 2^31-1 'loops around'), so, find that value for which that would be true (it's any number larger than SQRT(2147483647) - which you can just run on a calculator)) - you can stop if p is above that **or** if `p*p` is above n.
3. use `BigInteger`, now your code can handle any size input, though, it'll be incredibly slow compared to efficient prime-finders.

Comment: But before `p` ends up being 1, wouldn't it become 0 before that - resulting in a ArithmeticException when calculating `n%p`?

Comment: Before all that, `p` ends up being 2147483647, which will end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to input 2147483647, your program is treating it as an int, and due to the limitations of the data type, it overflows, causing unexpected behavior.
You can try this 'Long' instead of 'int', it shall return 2147483647 is prime. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is number overflow. Your numbers occupy a finite number of bits. A java int is of 32 bits, that is, the biggest number is 2^32 - 1, because we need half of the space to represent negatives.

Now, you are incrementing a number until its square is smaller or equal than your input and `isPrime` is false. But, if your input happens to be 2^32 - 1, then the first criteria will never be true. Hence, you will eventually have `p` overflowing the `int` boundaries and slowly but surely incrementing it until it's 1 and then your algorithm will claim it's not a prime. Instead of this, compute the square root of your input and use that as the limit of your loop and then it will work.

Comment: I'm happy to edit this answer if it has shotrcomings.

Comment: I did not downvote you but your answer is wrong in several ways.  First, your exponent is incorrect.   `2^16 - 1` is actually describing a `short` of all `one bits` or a `-1` (exponentiation comes before subtraction).    But for `ints`, It should be `(2^31)` is the smallest int with the high order bit set followed by all `0` bits.  And `(2^31)-1` is the largest int with the high order bit cleared followed by all `1` bits.

Comment: @WJS thanks for your comment. You are correct. I searched for the size of ints in Java (I have not been working with Java too much in the last 3 years) and found it to be 32, so I presumed it's signed 16 bits. But now, re-checking the same source I've seen it's actually signed 32 bits, so you are correct and it was an oversight on my part. Can you elaborate on what else is wrong in the answer?

Comment: Nothing else was incorrect, just the mathematics of the values.  For future use, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and `Integer.SIZE` may come in handy.  All the primitive wrapper classes have them defined.

Comment: @WJS makes sense. Yet, here we were interested in the actual value, too bad I had an oversight while looking for it. Thanks again for pointing that out.